# adding subtotals to multiple layers of pandas pivot-table

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Suppose I have a very basic dataset:

```
name   food      city   rating
paul   cream     LA     2
daniel chocolate NY     3
paul   chocolate LA     4
john   cream     NY     5
daniel jam       LA     1
daniel butter    NY     3
john   jam       NY     9
```

I want to compute the descriptive stats for each person's food preferences which is easy enough:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='rating', index=['city', 'name', 'food'], aggfunc=['count', 'nunique', 'sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', 'sem', 'median', 'mad', 'var', 'skew'], margins=True, margins_name="Total")
```

But I want to add subtotals for each name and city.

I can get subtotals for name and city in separate objects:

```
df2 = df.groupby('name').agg(['count', 'nunique', 'sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', 'sem', 'median', 'mad', 'var', 'skew'])
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.index + '_total', len(df2.index) * ['']])
```

```
df3 = df.groupby('city').agg(['count', 'nunique', 'sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', 'sem', 'median', 'mad', 'var', 'skew'])
df3.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df3.index + '_total', len(df3.index) * ['']])
```

But struggling to combine the three tables.
The output of df1 has columns for 'city' 'name' and 'food' on each row

```
city   name   food   count  nunique...
LA     daniel jam    1      1
       paul   choc   1      1
              cream  1      1
NY     daniel butter 1      1
```

but the outputs for df2 and df3 just have 'name' *df2) or 'city' (df3)

```
name          count nunique
daniel_total  3     1
john_total    2     1
```

I want to merge these files so the name totals are placed in the 'name' column and the city totals in the 'city' like so:

```
city  name         food   count
LA    daniel       jam    1
      paul         choc   1
                   cream  1
LA_total                  3
NY    daniel       butter 1
NY_total                  2
      daniel_total        3
      john_total          2
      paul_total          2
```

I've tried using pandas concat, but it groups the descriptive columns together

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3].sort_index()
```

I think I need to tell python which column to join the df2 and df3 datasets into but not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['city','name']).agg(['count', 'nunique', 'sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', 'sem', 'median', 'mad', 'var', 'skew'])
df2 = df2.rename(index=lambda x: x+'_total', level=1)
df2 = df2.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
df2 = df2.assign(food='').set_index('food', append=True)

df3 = df.groupby('city').agg(['count', 'nunique', 'sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', 'sem', 'median', 'mad', 'var', 'skew'])
df3.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df3.index + '_total', len(df3.index) * ['']])
df3 = df3.assign(name='', food='').set_index(['name','food'], append=True)
df3 = df3.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)

df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).sort_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
                                 count nunique    sum    min    max      mean       std       sem median       mad       var      skew
                                rating  rating rating rating rating    rating    rating    rating rating    rating    rating    rating
city     name         food                                                                                                            
LA       daniel       jam            1       1      1      1      1  1.000000       NaN       NaN      1  0.000000       NaN       NaN
         daniel_total                1       1      1      1      1  1.000000       NaN       NaN      1  0.000000       NaN       NaN
         paul         chocolate      1       1      4      4      4  4.000000       NaN       NaN      4  0.000000       NaN       NaN
                      cream          1       1      2      2      2  2.000000       NaN       NaN      2  0.000000       NaN       NaN
         paul_total                  2       2      6      2      4  3.000000  1.414214  1.000000      3  1.000000  2.000000       NaN
LA_total                             3       3      7      1      4  2.333333  1.527525  0.881917      2  1.111111  2.333333  0.935220
NY       daniel       butter         1       1      3      3      3  3.000000       NaN       NaN      3  0.000000       NaN       NaN
                      chocolate      1       1      3      3      3  3.000000       NaN       NaN      3  0.000000       NaN       NaN
         daniel_total                2       1      6      3      3  3.000000  0.000000  0.000000      3  0.000000  0.000000       NaN
         john         cream          1       1      5      5      5  5.000000       NaN       NaN      5  0.000000       NaN       NaN
                      jam            1       1      9      9      9  9.000000       NaN       NaN      9  0.000000       NaN       NaN
         john_total                  2       2     14      5      9  7.000000  2.828427  2.000000      7  2.000000  8.000000       NaN
NY_total                             4       3     20      3      9  5.000000  2.828427  1.414214      4  2.000000  8.000000  1.414214
Total                                7       6     27      1      9  3.857143  2.609506  0.986301      3  1.836735  6.809524  1.398866
```